# Compute Rolling Rank of Xts Column

Tags: r

I am an r beginner and I have an xts object with 1 column and 10000 rows, data does contain some NA's.  I am trying to find the rank of each value within the next 4 values in the same column.  For example if I have these values in col 1:

```
01/02/2018  25
12/29/2017  16
12/28/2017  22
12/27/2017  6
12/26/2017  17
12/21/2017  11
```

I want this result:

```
01/02/2018  1   (25 is rank 1 of 25,16,22,6)
12/29/2017  3   (16 is rank 3 of 16,22,6,17)
12/28/2017  1   (22 is rank 1 of 22,6,17,11)
```

I have tried using rank function multiple different ways including:

```
apply(xts, 2, rank)
```

This ranks each value within the entire xts as opposed to ranking each value  within the preceding 4 values.  I can't seem to figure this out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollapply`:

```
library(zoo);
window <- 4;
df2 <- as.data.frame(replace(df, 2, rollapply(zoo(
    df[, 2]),
    window, 
    function(x) (window + 1 - rank(x))[1],
    align = "left", fill = NA)));
df2[complete.cases(df2), ];
#    V1 V2
#1 2018-01-02  1
#2 2017-12-29  3
#3 2017-12-28  1
```

---

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "01/02/2018  25
12/29/2017  16
12/28/2017  22
12/27/2017  6
12/26/2017  17
12/21/2017  11", header = F)
```